# PHP refuses to load shared extensions on Mac OS X

Tags: php, apc, pecl

I have a PHP extension (*APC*) which I've built using PECL. I've added it to the config file by adding this :

> extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so

However PHP ignores the extension completely, without any errors or anything. **Why does that happen?**

My PHP configure command:

> './configure' \ '--with-apxs2' \
>   '--enable-gd-native-ttf' \
>   '--with-curl' \ '--with-gd' \
>   '--with-freetype-dir=/opt/X11/' \
>   '--with-jpeg-dir=/opt/local/' \
>   '--with-png-dir=/opt/local/' \
>   '--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql' \
>   '--without-iconv' \ '--with-mm' \
>   '--with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config'
>   \ '--with-imagick=/opt/local/' \
>   '--enable-mbstring' \
>   '--with-libmemcached-dir=/opt/local' \
>   '--enable-memcached' \ "$@"

P.S. Same thing happened with memcached extension, so I've statically linked it into PHP. I can't do that with APC because it causes linking errors when I link it into PHP, so I have to build it as a shared extension.

P.S.2: The extension_dir way doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're actually getting the php.ini you think you are, not one elsewhere (like the default OS X php config). Does phpinfo() show anything interesting?

Comment: Yes, I'm on /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Comment: Had to accept something. Still haven't sorted it out, it works on the development server so I'm fine for now.